# Python I have device ID how to get dev address

Tags: python, linux, usb, pyserial, pyudev

I have a USB device, it may not be connected to the same port everytime it is plugged into the PC, how can i find it's dev-address given that I have its UID ?

```
import serial.tools.list_ports as port

portlist = list(port.comports())
for p in portlist:
  print p
```

gives me the output :

```
/dev/ttyS0 - ttyS0
/dev/ttyUSB1 - USB2.0-Serial
/dev/ttyUSB0 - FT232R USB UART
```

my device is `FT232R USB UART` ,currently whose dev address is `/dev/ttyUSB0` ,and I need this in my program for serial  r/w (`ser = serial.Serial(port, baud)`).But if multiple devices are connected previously and I plug in this device, it changes this address, my question is how can I find out this address every time I plug my device?

Comment: Hi there, could you please provide code you already done and make your question more specific (with examples and more explanations)?

Comment: I have updated the question with my code, please have a look.

Comment: One of solutions is to write `udev` rule to have a persistent name for your device: http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/

Comment: @MichaelO. , will I have to do this, in every system I run my program on ?(sorry for the stupid question, I've never done this before) . If so, then it would be a temporary solution.

Comment: @PratikKumar Unfortunately, yes, you have to create a rule for every system. But what's wrong with calling list_ports and finding your device, as you posted here?

Comment: @MichaelO. If I type `print portlist`  I get `[<serial.tools.list_ports_linux.SysFS object at 0x7f02c4944650>, <serial.tools.list_ports_linux.SysFS object at 0x7f02c4944690>, <serial.tools.list_ports_linux.SysFS object at 0x7f02c49448d0>]` , how can I use this to find out my device's address ? I assumed that using UID or device name as a filter I may be able to locate the dev address.

Comment: If you have any suggestions on modifying my code, by which I can achieve the desired result, please suggest them.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `pyusb`. If your system uses `udev` to manage *hot-plug* devices (like most Linux distributions do nowadays) you could use `pyudev` library to look up your device. Or even simpler, find your device in `/dev/serial/by-id` and use that symlink instead of `/dev/ttyUSBx` in your code. It is guaranteed to stay the same regardless of the order of connection as long you do not connect another device with the same *serial number*.

Otherwise:

```
import serial

UID = '12345678'
ports = {p.serial_number:p.device for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports() if p.serial_number}
if UID in ports:
    port = serial.Serial(ports[UID], ...)
```